# Disable a specific Link with javascript, keep others active

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, navigation

I have this structure and want to disable certain Links without having an effect on other Links in a certain div.

```
<div class="navigation">
<a href"#">DISABLE THIS LINK</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
</ul>
<a href"#">DISABLE THIS LINK</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
</ul>
<a href"#">DISABLE THIS LINK</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
<li><a href="#">KEEP THIS LINK ENABLED</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried it with something like this:

```
$(".navigation a").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
$(".subitem a").click(function(){ return true; });
```

But this didn't work.

Any ideas how i can disable the "DISABLE THIS LINK" and keep the others enabled without changing the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing the selector.

(".navigation a") will select all 'a' tags within the class .navigation, if you change this to (".navigation > a"), it will only select the direct child 'a' elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the link that is clicked has the parent element with `class=".submenu"`, if it does, it will evaluate the statement to true, and everything will work as normal. If it's not a chil of `.submenu`, then you call `e.preventDefault()` so it won't do anything on click.

```
$(".navigation a").click(function(e){
    if ($(this).parent().parent('.submenu')) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just select the direct children of your navigation DIV.

```
$(".navigation").children('a').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8QuWj/3/